# Cross platform firemonkey dll

Tags: delphi, dll, cross-platform, firemonkey, dylib

I have main VCL application which uses dll plugins (VCL too).

I started with conversion of plugins from VCL to Firemonkey. I am now loading some firemonkey dll's with VCL app. Of course I am taking care of GDI+ loading and unloading as suggested by Stephen Ball  (http://blogs.embarcadero.com/stephenball/2011/10/10/writing-a-firemonkey-dll-for-use-with-a-vcl-application/)

I also made small workaround to automatically load and unload GDI+ inside dll instead in caller app to keep it easier for use with eg. C++, C# etc.. So caller app doesn't need to explicitly load GDI+ (it's done by plugin). But still when working on Windows I have to include WinAPI.GDIPOBJ in my DLL.

My question how this could be done on MacOs while there is no WinAPI.GDIPOBJ? As I am aware Firemonkey uses OpenGL on MacOs.

I would like to keep my dylib available for other non-firemonkey callers(apps) on MacOs.

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to `IFDEF` the DLL code so it uses `WinAPI.GDIPOBJ` only on Windows and not on OSX: `uses ...{$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}, Winapi.GDIPOBJ{$ENDIF};`

Comment: That's it? I don't need to do anything special with the initialisation like with Gdi+ where I need to manually call Initialization and Deinitialization routines? I wish there was documentation about firemonkey internals.

Comment: You would also have to `IFDEF` your `initialization` and `finalization` code as well.  This is not really a FireMonkey issue, just a general cross-platform coding issue. Obviously, you have to `IFDEF` any platform-specific code. Read the documentation for a list of platform values you can check for if your `{$IFDEF}`/`{$IF}` statements: [Conditional compilation (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Conditional_compilation_(Delphi)).

Comment: Sure. That makes sense. I am already using IFDEFs to use platform specific functions however I wasn't sure how it is with OpenGl on MacOs in my case. So if I compile it for win it will use Gdi+ and custom initialization and if I compile it for Mac it will use opengl automatically. Thanks Remy.